# Idiom for one who tries to forget problems instead of solving them

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

Is there an idiom for **one who when faces problems or obstacles tries to forget them instead of solving them** ?

Comment: wishful thinker, escapist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Bury your head in the sand](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bury+head+in+the+sand)*** can be used to convey the meaning you are suggesting:

> to refuse to think about an unpleasant situation, hoping that it will improve so that you will not have to deal with it
>
> - *Parents said bullying was being ignored, and accused the headmaster of burying his head in the sand.*

(Alludes to an ostrich, which is believed incorrectly to hide its head in a hole in the ground when it sees danger)

(Cambridge Idioms Dictionary)

Comment: According to the [OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ostrich), it would also be correct to call that person an ostrich; for the reason you mentioned.